# Prevent resize of UIViewController when changing orientation

Tags: ios

The Maps app has a "custom" behaviour and doesn't resize the bottom menu when in landscape orientation.
What's the best way to achieve the same effect, short of resizing the view manually on every orientation change?

See attached images to get a better understanding.

[image: portrait]

[image: landscape]

Comment: remove the constraint in landscape mode

Answer (score 0):

This is done using size classes.
The easiest way to do it is to use the size classes right from your storyboard.
Right next to constraints and size related options from the size inspector you have this little **+** sign.
Hit it to define a different behavior for each size class.
See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/TheAdaptiveModel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH19-SW1) for more, including how to use size classes from your code.

[image: Adding size class variations via a storyboard]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Moshe Gottlieb.  
Unfortunately, that works on constraints, which I don't have in the case of a UIViewController.

Comment: @tagyro , I may be missing something out here - your view controller was added somehow, wasn't it? it's usually done using storyboards but can be done using code too. Either way, it has a view in it, and that view _usually_ has constraints. Isn't it the case? please share some code so I'd know how to help you.

Comment: I'm using [ISHPullUP](https://github.com/iosphere/ISHPullUp) to present the "menu". But the "menu" itself is a view-controller (yes, it has a view, but I would like to prevent changing the size of that "manually" and I'm looking for a more "elegant" solution.

Comment: I guess your 3rd party controller should have allowed customization based on size classes, it doesn't look like it's the case, I looked inside the code, and it doesn't even work with auto layout. You will need to modify `ISHPullUpViewController.m` and change the frame of `dimmingView` when the orientation changes, but really, you're just asking for trouble if you do that as there's a whole lot of code in there that just isn't designed for this.

Comment: Just to be clear - when I wrote _doesn't even work with auto layout_ I wasn't implying that's wrong or anything.